# Post-receive hook after changing directories

Tags: git, laravel-4

what would be the correct way of changing directories, running some commands, then running a checkout from git.

Basically, my process is this:

1. switch directories
2. put the application in maintenance mode
3. run the checkout
4. exit

I get stuck at 3. Basically if I try to checkout, I get the "not a git repository" error. I understand why. I'm curious if there's a better way to run the checkout command from the proper location without doing another directory change.

Here's what I have now

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    case $branch in
    "testing")
        echo "testing branch"
        DEPLOYDIR=../testing_html
        cd $DEPLOYDIR
        php artisan down
        #php artisan migrate:rollback --env=srv-testing
        GIT_WORK_TREE="$DEPLOYDIR" git checkout -f
        #php artisan migrate --seed --env=srv-testing
        #php artisan up
        #echo "Deployment to testing environment complete"
        ;;
    *)echo "doing nothing";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert:

```
export GIT_DIR=$PWD
```

before the first `cd`, and `DEPLOYDIR` should not be a relative path. Use:

```
DEPLOYDIR=$PWD/../testing_html
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I still need to cd back and forth from the DEPLOYDIR but maybe there isn't a way around that.